# Parsing error, missing semicolon on my Type checker function

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, parsing, eslint

I have created a correct Type checker function but the Parser tells me there is a missing semicolon but i don't know where.

**My code**

```
export const IsFirestoreUserData = (toVerify: any): toVerify is FirestoreUserData => {

  if (toVerify.profile === undefined) return false;
  if (toVerify.profile.name === undefined) return false;
  if (toVerify.profile.surname === undefined) return false;
  if (toVerify.conversations === undefined) return false;
  if (typeof toVerify.conversations !== "object") return false;

  return true;
};
```

**The error**

```
  Line 37:2:  Parsing error: Missing semicolon

  35 | export const IsFirestoreUserData = (
  36 |   toVerify: any
> 37 | ): toVerify is FirestoreUserData => {
     |  ^
  38 |   if (toVerify.profile === undefined) return false;
  39 |   if (toVerify.profile.name === undefined) return false;
  40 |   if (toVerify.profile.surname === undefined) return false;
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: does your file have a `.ts` extension? do you have the typescript eslint extensions?

Comment: Everything is ok, it's a .ts file and eslint is using my workspace typescript

Comment: please share that configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For others finding this same issue, it could be because you needed to restart ESLint after a configuration change such as adding the TypeScript parser.

You can do this by restarting VS Code, reloading VS Code, restarting the extension host, or **restarting the VS Code ESLint server (fastest)**.

1. Press `ctrl` + `shift` + `p` (or your keybinding for opening the command palette)
2. Type `restart eslint`
3. Press `enter`
4. Wait for ESLint to come back online

Answer (score 5):

Idk why but i've restarted VSCode and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this error using below plugin.

```
'@storybook/preset-typescript'
```

Install the plugin :

```
npm install --save-dev @storybook/preset-typescript
```

Then add the same to addOns Array in main.js